# Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Startup Failed with "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, jvm, flash-builder, startup

When I try to start Adobe Flash Builder 4.7, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine
```

Before it was working perfectly. The problem started to occur after I set up my MacOSX for a new project.  But I didn't change any *.ini file in the Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 installation directory.

I Googled a lot, everyone gave the similar answer: change the *.ini files. I found 3 files:

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.ini
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Builder 4.ini
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini
```

I tried to change the following values as instructed:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=64m
```

But not working at all. So what values are you guys using if my physical memory is 4GB? (my MacOSX has 4GB memory).

BTW, I did (re)install Java when setting up my MacOSX for a new project, and here is my java info:

```
[plee@pleemac ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
[plee@pleemac ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
[plee@pleemac ~]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ridiculous! But I'm not sure. It seems Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 does NOT support Java 1.7.

After I install Apple's Java 1.6 from:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

I am able to open Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.

Hmmm, now I need to install Java 1.7 in a very special way for my new project. Actually I don't know how. But Thank god, I finally could use my Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 again!

Comment: Odd, I'm having the opposite problem: I have 1.6.0_25 installed, and no Java 7 and am getting this message.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution on Sierra for Flash Builder **4.6**:
I'm just set JAVA_HOME environment to java 1.6

install java 1.6 from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

from terminal:

`cd /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)"
./eclipse`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I started eclipse from the terminal (see below) and saw that the JavaVM was complaining about a library from an old version 1.7JDK. When I Looked in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines I saw that after performing updates on the JDK, the old installs (and updates) were still installed. I uninstalled all JDK installation folders except for the most recent. See Oracle site for uninstall instructions (you basically just delete them) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

To open Eclipse from terminal, enter: cd /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/

then enter: ./eclipse

Comment: Hmmm, I only have one jdk installed: `l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Dec 17 16:44 jdk1.7.0_45.jdk`

Answer (score 0):

I just installed java 1.6 from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572, and FlashBuilder 4.6 on MacOS Mojave is functional again.